# How to move from test automation to devops?

Tags: automated-testing, continuous-integration, career-development

I have a background as a developer, but have been working on test automation here in the UK for the last years. I work a lot with Java, Webdriver and Jenkins/continuous deivery - but I am very interested in "switching" career to more devops since I already love and work with automation.

How do you make such a transition and where do you begin?

Comment: Start by googling this and other forums. this question is asked every other week, like: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3648/software-testing-a-first-step-to-development

Comment: @PeterMasiar This question seems a bit different/unique in that they're looking to transition to DevOps, not Dev.

Comment: So to improve the question, OP could link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps, to other similar articles, and how provided answers lack the specifics for OP's situation. Basically, to show doing homework research, to show effort.

Answer (score 2):

Generally I would consider some of the key requirements for an entry level position to be

- background as a developer
- experience with OO such as Java
- practical experience with automation
- familiarity with CI and Jenkins
- enthusiasm about devops

In other words, you are already qualified.

If you wish to have a more mid-level or senior position then you will have to study / be questioned about / be knowledge in

- Servers, flavors and capabilities
- Unix, linux, osx, windows
- Shell scripting
- Packaging and deploying applications
- Release and Change management
- Monitor tools for performance and end user experience